# CSS background image not appearing in Safari

Tags: css, image, background, safari

I have the very simple task of applying a background image to a DIV. I can view the image with every other browser except Safari. Can someone take a look at my CSS and site and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

CSS:

```
#intro2services {
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0)), url(../img/colorpencils.jpg) fixed;
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Site:
www.designedbysheldon.com

Comment: The image with the gradient shows up in Chrome 39, Safari 8, but had issues in Firefox (all Mac).

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your site for a few minutes, and I suggest breaking up your styles for the background rather than condensing some while having others declared on their own. Change your CSS to:

```
#intro2services {
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0)),url('../img/colorpencils.jpg'); /* Firefox-specific background styles */
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0)), url('../img/colorpencils.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

That removed the repeat, applied the gradient, and applied the `cover` sizing correctly. This is tested and working in Chrome and Safari. Firefox only works when the `-moz` vendor prefix is added. You can add the other vendor prefixes to be safe, but [gradients are implemented](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) in the other major browsers at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue with Safari. Most of the time, adding a negative z-index to your style, will solve the issue.

```
z-index:-1:
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Safari--or at least some versions of it--refuses to apply CSS to form fields, so if you have a clever little search box like I do, Safari won't render any CSS applied to it.  I thought it was specific to my use of SVGs and then I thought it had something to do with the short code. I was stuck until I found an obscure post on GitHub from a MarcHaunschild from 2011 discussing this behavior.  Anyway in the case that you're trying to style a field such as a search box, here's the fix.

Add the following to your CSS:

```
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
```