# Background fixed image issue with linear gradient on safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have two fixed images on my website. The first one without linear gradient works fine on safari but as soon as I try to apply linear-gradient to the second image it disappears. I put -webkit- prefix but no success. I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients) as well. Can someone tell me what is causing this issue ?

```
.intro { 
-webkit-background: url('../images/intro.jpg') no-repeat;
background: url('../images/intro.jpg') no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
padding-top: 150px;
padding-bottom: 120px;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
.second-bg {
    background:  linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('../images/contact.jpg') no-repeat;
    background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('../images/contact.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 100px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies on linear gradient (to bottom .... ) I changed it to (left bottom ... )

```
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 29%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('../images/contact.jpg') no-repeat;
```

and solved the problem. Another thing to point out is the image has to come after gradient otherwise it will not work.

Solution:

1. change the gradient to (left bottom ...)
2. image url has to come after gradient

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting image first and then the linear-gradient?

```
background:  url('../images/contact.jpg') no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%) no-repeat;
background:  url('../images/contact.jpg') no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%) no-repeat;
```

The image is there, but it's under linear-gradient and therefore not visible.

Comment: I did try ... I tried every possible way and can't find out what it is ?

Comment: Maybe this will help you [Safari Gradients Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Gradients/Gradient.html)

Comment: Have you tried with different image? [see related bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341728/background-image-not-showing-in-safari) You could also try setting z-index: -1; as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749767/css-background-image-not-appearing-in-safari)

Comment: z-index: -1; did not help

Comment: What Safari version are you targeting?

Comment: I found the issue and answered to my question. Thank you

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark your answer as correct one.