# Css Background property not working in safari browser

Tags: html, css

CSS `background` isn't working on Safari browser:

```
header {
    color: #007AC9 !important;
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60) ),url('/Images/signUp.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Define "not working". What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? What version of Safari are you testing in? Have you checked [that it actually supported in that version](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)? Provide a [MCVE], you have no HTML in your example, but you [could provide a live demo in the question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). You say it doesn't work in Safari, but does it work anywhere else? What browsers have you successfully tested this in?

Comment: Uhh, are you sure that !important is important?

Comment: Not sure if this will work... try adding `z-index:-1;` to the style

Comment: @TheCodesee — I can't think of any circumstance where that would have a positive impact. In this case it shouldn't do anything at all since the element is not positioned.

Comment: @Quentin I didn't think it would... I only mentioned it because it was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28005407/5798798

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   header {
    color: #007AC9 !important;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60) ),url('/Images/signUp.jpg');
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60) ),url('/Images/signUp.jpg');
}
```